# Mix Panel Integration with Angular 2

Tags: angular, mixpanel, angulartics2

I am trying to Integrate my angular project with Mix Panel. For this purpose I tried a lot of online solutions provided but problem is that the solutions provided are either outdated or give incomplete or ambiguous information. Can anybody give a good tutorial or can anyone provide a minimal code for mixpanel integration. Thanks in advance :)